# How to open jenkins in tomcat docker container

Tags: docker, tomcat

So i have deployed jenkins.war into the tomcat docker container but apparently when i try to open this jenkins.war file i end up getting HTTP Status 404 – Not Found error,

[image]

[image]

What i expect is a jenkins page to be opened, I went through the docker logs and i found these errors

```
17-Sep-2020 10:21:25.176 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan Failed to scan JAR [war:file:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/jenkins.war*/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-2.5.6.SEC03.jar] from /WEB-INF/lib
 java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/local/tomcat/temp/jar_cache7070370173706501058.tmp
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
17-Sep-2020 10:21:26.629 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Sep-2020 10:21:26.954 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
17-Sep-2020 10:21:26.960 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/jenkins] startup failed due to previous errors
```

What is it that i'm missing, Please help me out with your suggestions.

Comment: Why not use Jenkins' Docker image instead?

Comment: @Konrad Botor Well my work requirement is to open jenkins in tomcat docker image via helm charts.(Which will be deployed through jenkins pipeline scripting)